Using Angular 18 - Subscribe not working as expected
I am trying to make a post request to an api. My intention is to trigger success if the operation goes through, but so far the function below does not work as expected.
I tried this:
this.Repository.getTokens(payload).subscribe({
        complete: () => {
          const message = `${payload.amount} test Lto sent!!`;
          this.openSnackBar(message);
        },
        error: () => {
          const message = `You cannot request tokens at this time!`;
          this.openSnackBar(message);
        },
      });

Note I also tried using next instead of complete.
The getTokens function:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { requestPayload } from '../types/requestPayload';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class Repository {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getTokens(data: requestPayload): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:4000/faucet/`, data, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  }
}


can you add the getTokens function?

I think this answer will be insightful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75063368/4378578. Most likely a take(1) will be what you are looking for, or instead use next: () => {}
